# Exporting max values of different csv files in to one

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I got 3 datasets which contain the flow in m3/s per location. Dataset 1 is a 5 year ARI flood, Dataset 2 is a 20 year ARI flood and Dataset 3 is a 50 year ARI flood.
Per location I found the maximum discharge (5,20 & 50)

Code:

```
for key in Data_5_ARI_RunID_Flow_New.keys():

    m = key   
    y5F_RunID = Data_5_ARI_RunID_Flow_New.loc[:,m]
    y20F_RunID = Data_20_ARI_RunID_Flow_New.loc[:,m]
    y50F_RunID = Data_50_ARI_RunID_Flow_New.loc[:,m]                                                                     
    max_y5F = max(y5F_RunID)    
    max_y20F = max(y20F_RunID)    
    max_y50F = max(y50F_RunID)
    Max_DataID = m, max_y5F, max_y20F, max_y50F
    print (Max_DataID)
```

The output is like this:

```
('G60_18', 44.0514, 47.625, 56.1275)
('Area5_11', 1028.4065, 1191.5946, 1475.9685)
('Area5_12', 1017.8286, 1139.2628, 1424.4304)
('Area5_13', 994.5626, 1220.0084, 1501.1483)
('Area5_14', 995.9636, 1191.8066, 1517.4541)
```

Now I want to export this result to a csv file, but I don't know how. I used this line of code, but it didn't work:

```
Max_DataID.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Max_DataID.csv', sep=',', index = False)
```

Comment: What gives you print type(UMax_DataID)?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Are you using Pandas or some other library that has a `to_csv` function, or were you just hoping for magic? If the former, which library, and did you read the docs for it?

Comment: I loaded the three csv files with read_csv(...). Now i have selected the max values per column of the three csv files. Now I want to export these max values per location to a new csv file. However I'm didn't manage to execute the last step.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this file name myexample.csv with specific path where you want to create the file.**
**Please check that Max_DataID is a iterable value. And as your reference the values are in form of tuple so I use list() to convert tuples into list and that will be supported values for writerow in csv.**

```
import csv
file = open('myexample.csv', 'wb')
filewriter = csv.writer(file,delimiter =',')
for data in Max_DataID:
    filewriter.writerow(list(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t')
```

Also, if you want to split it into chunks, like 10,000 rows, or whatever, you can do this.

```
import pandas as pd
for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('C:/your_path_here/main.csv', chunksize=10000)):
chunk.to_csv('chunk{}.csv'.format(i))
```